# Chromecast failure callbacks on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, chromecast

I'm interested to know if there is a way to get a callback when there are chromecast casting failures:

1. The user start to cast something from my app, background the app and start casting a different asset from a different application like YouTube/Spotify
2. When there is a power drop and the chromecast disconnected from the wifi.
3. Connectivity issues with chromecast and the router

I'm currently using RemoteMediaClient with setResultCallback but setResultCallback is never been called when there is one of those failures.

Answer (score 0):

There is a session manager listener , you can use it

```
val mSessionManagerListener = object : SessionManagerListener<CastSession> {
            override fun onSessionEnded(session: CastSession, error: Int) {
                onApplicationDisconnected()
            }

            override fun onSessionResumed(session: CastSession, wasSuspended: Boolean) {
                onApplicationConnected(session)
            }

            override fun onSessionResumeFailed(session: CastSession, error: Int) {
                onApplicationDisconnected()
                showToast("ResumeFailed $error")
            }

            override fun onSessionStarted(session: CastSession, sessionId: String) {
                onApplicationConnected(session)
            }

            override fun onSessionStartFailed(session: CastSession, error: Int) {
                onApplicationDisconnected()
                showToast("Error $error")
            }

            override fun onSessionStarting(session: CastSession) {}
            override fun onSessionEnding(session: CastSession) {}
            override fun onSessionResuming(session: CastSession, sessionId: String) {}
            override fun onSessionSuspended(session: CastSession, reason: Int) {}
            private fun onApplicationConnected(castSession: CastSession) {
                mCastSession = castSession

               
            }

            private fun onApplicationDisconnected() {
               
            }
        }


        mCastContext?.sessionManager?.addSessionManagerListener(
            mSessionManagerListener!!,
            CastSession::class.java
        )
```